# Как правильно сказать?

Tags: лингвистика

Он *лазил* в холодильник или *лез*?

Answer (score 6):

Это зависит ситуации.

Оказывается, наш кот лазил в холодильник.
В следующий раз, когда он лез в холодильник, его схватили за хвост и отчитали.

В первом случае речь о предположительно неоднократном действии (был, по крайней мере, один случай, когда залез), во втором - об однократном и незавершённом.